# Running Matplotlib or enthought.mayavi.mlab from a py-shell inside Emacs on Windows

Tags: python, emacs, pymacs

I can run the following code fine from a regular cmd shell:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
plt.show()
```

It launches a Matplotlib window.
However, running inside Emacs using shell or py-shell: the buffer just hangs and no window is launched. What's going on here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Works for me (Debian Linux, Emacs 23.2.1, Python 2.6.6, matplotlib 0.99.3).  What platform and software versions are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with [ipython.el](http://ipython.scipy.org/dist/ipython.el).

I had to add modify python26\scripts\ipython.bat:

```
@"c:\Python26\python.exe" "-i" "c:\Python26\scripts\ipython.py" "-wthread" %*
```

Then in Emacs:

```
(setq ipython-command "c:/python26/scripts/ipython.bat")
(require 'ipython)
(py-shell)
```

Answer (score 0):

After a tremendous amount of time and posting the bug on the matplotlib project page and the python-mode page I found out that supplying the arguments `console --matplotlib` in ipython.bat will do the trick with Matplotlib 1.3.1 and IPython 1.2.0.

This is what I have in my *iphython.bat* file:

```
@python.exe -i D:\devel\Python27\Scripts\ipython-script.py console --matplotlib %*
```