# Python shell in Emacs freezes when using matplotlib

Tags: python, emacs, matplotlib

I previously thought that was the issue with IPython, but today I tested again, here is what I did:

1. Run `emacs -Q` in cmd window
2. Open a .py file
3. `M-x`, then run `python-shell-switch-to-shell`, `RET`, and `RET`. Then I have the Python shell ready
4. I in put the following code then:

> ```
> Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> >>> plt.ion()
> >>> plt.plot([1,2,3])
> [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x03068610>]
> >>>
> ```

Actually after this, no figure shows up, and the shell is frozen, e.g., when I input:

> ```
> >>> print("hello")
> ```

nothing happened...I haven't tested other plotting tools but matplotlib. I don't know if it is a bug. I've searched for a while, here and though Google, but no luck. My system is: Emacs 24.3 32 bit for Windows, under Windows 7. If others can duplicate same issue as here, I will report this as a bug.

I used IPython as the Python shell by:

```
C:/Python27/python.exe -i C:/Python27/Scripts/ipython-script.py --pylab
```

Then, I input `figure(); plot([1,2,3])`, as expected, the figure popup and freezes. Then I did: `C-c C-d` which runs `comint-send-eof`, and the figure actually get **updated**! But my IPython shell session is also terminated with the following message:

```
In [6]:
Do you really want to exit ([y]/n)?
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python27/Scripts/ipython-script.py", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('ipython==0.13.1', 'console_scripts', 'ipython')()
SystemExit

If you suspect this is an IPython bug, please report it at:
https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues
or send an email to the mailing list at ipython-dev@scipy.org

You can print a more detailed traceback right now with "%tb", or use "%debug"
to interactively debug it.

Extra-detailed tracebacks for bug-reporting purposes can be enabled via:
%config Application.verbose_crash=True
```

Any helpful clue here?!

Comment: I tried it on GNU Emacs 24.2.1 on Fedora 18 and it works fine, sorry. But the hook on my system is ``python-switch-to-python``.

Comment: you are having issues with the gui main loop.  What backend are you using?  Try configuring it to use `ipython --pylab` instead of `python`

Comment: @tcaswell i actually tried different backends using matplotlib.use(), does not work. But in cmd window, it works. i also tried ipython, there is a figure window shows up, but it freezes without plot.I believe this post describes the same issue [here on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101800/emacs-python-inferior-shell-not-showing-prompt-after-matplotlib-show-command), almost 1 year past, still no true answer to the question... I believe it is duplicable if you dont mind to try it with same configuration

Comment: I don't have a windows box set up to do any real work.  Are you passing python the proper threading arguments when you start the interpreter?  `matploblib.use()` needs to be run before you import `plt`.  I suspect your system is not configured quite right.

Comment: here is my command for Run Python shell in emacs: `C:/Python27/python.exe -i C:/Python27/Scripts/ipython-script.py --pylab` , my ipython is 0.13.2, my python is 2.7.5, the default backend is : TkAgg, As i said, it works under cmd window, so i believe it is not the backend cause the problem. I also tried QT.

Comment: Today i tested one more time and find something that maybe helpful to  solve the problem, i 've added it to the question. however, i am a newbie of emacs and elisp, i wish sb. else who is familiar with python.el and emacs can help to solve the problem with the added info above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one solution is:

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "C:\\YourPython3Dist\\python.exe"
      python-shell-interpreter-args "-i C:\\YourPython3Dist\\Scripts\\ipython3-script.py console --pylab=qt")
```

**The Argument `console` in the call of ipython-script.py is the important one!**

In Python 3 with qt backend it works for me. I don't know how it works with py 2.7. (should be no problem if these arguments are supported for `ipytho-script.py`)

Comment: you are the man made my life easier! it works for python 2.7 as well!

Comment: Yea when they introduced the console argument it started working. I had this problem prior to version 1.0 of Ipython

Comment: @siegfried I am using the WinPython distribution and `ipython3-script.py` is not in the distribution. Any idea what this like should look like in this setup? I am experiencing the same hanging behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would take sometime until the problem is fixed.  Until some Windows user actually debugs python.el.

Until then, why not try [Emacs IPython Notebook](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-ipython-notebook#readme)?  It is a better IPython binding for Emacs.  You don't need to use the notebook part.  You can think it as a replacement for python shell in python.el.  (disclaimer: I am the author)

Comment: My experience is that ipython is not so great for windows, the notebook often has kernel crash for me, i tried on different machine but same thing happens. I believe that is because the ipython notebook itself requires to set up an http server whose compatibility is not perfect under Windows. Anyway, thanks for making EIN, its a great package for Emacs, and i am actually using it.

Comment: If it is kernel, the problem is probably zmq, not http (tornado).  Did you send a bug report?  I think IPython dev is quicker to fix the problem when it comes to Windows.  And glad you like EIN :)

Comment: if you have time ,could you please help to take a look at the question updates? i wonder if that can help to solve the problem, thanks!

Comment: I don't know much about python.el internal, so I don't know how to fix.  I think you can just send a bug report to emacs devel.