# Emacs + Python + matplotlib + win7 = freeze

Tags: python, matplotlib, emacs

In GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2015-11-10, using run-python I start

```
Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  7 2015, 15:00:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>>>
>>>
```

It works fine for most things I have tested. Matplotlib, however, freezes without any graphs:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.plot([1,3,2])
>>> [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0000000004ED0EF0>]
```

After that, emacs freezes. If I switch to ipython interpreter or run the code from same python version in the console it works fine. Also, on my Mac and Linux boxes there are no problems with the emacs setup so it seems to be a win7 issue.

I really would like to use emacs as my python environment, but I need matplotlib.

Anyone else using Anaconda-Python, emacs and matplotlib on Win7 who got it working? Or any tips on how to debug?

Comment: may be the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117074/python-shell-in-emacs-freezes-when-using-matplotlib